# Do Windows or browsers save the signature of X509 certificate?

Tags: c#, firefox, cryptography, x509certificate

Windows has classes `X509Certificate2` and `X509Certificate` for certificate data. But none provides the original signature, only the thumbprint. They provide the field `RawData` but it is only the certificate itself because I ran a hash on it and it matches the hash provided by X509Certificate.

Windows has tools to save each certificate into a file of different formats but none of them appears to include the signature. Firefox has its own utility to display a certificate where it displays signature but it appears to be a bug because the signature matches the last bytes of `RawData` returned by `X509Certificate`, and this `RawData` is the raw certificate without the signature.

I tried both the CA certificates and servers certificates from a HTTPS session and none of them include the signature. It seems like Windows validates the signature, converts it into thumbprint, and just throws away the signature. Why?

Comment: "What would you do, if I sang out of tune?" -- Ringo Starr.  
What would you do with the signature if you could get it?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: yes, the signature is saved, *even if it is not shown*. The signature is required to create a *trust chain*. The signature consists of a large amount of binary data, so it is not all that useful to show it to the user.

---

You're confused. The last parts of a certificate *is* the signature value, as you can see [in the X.509 specifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1).

The hash over the certificate that is shown is *not* the hash that is used to generate the signature. It is a separate hash over all of the binary data that make up the certificate *including the signature*, while the hash within the certificate is only over the [`TBSCertificate`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2) - the To Be Signed" part of the certificate.

Furthermore, the thumbprints over *all certificates* are generally calculated using one specific hash algorithm. This makes it easy to compare thumbprints. The hash algorithm that is used for the signature is specified in the certificate itself - comprehensively called `signatureAlgorithm`. Although it could be the same algorithm as the thumbprint, it is usually a more modern hash function that doesn't allow collisions. The thumbprint is generally still SHA-1 or MD-5 which is less secure, but easier for humans to grok.

Comment: You need to look up the class X509Certificate. It provides GetCertHash(). It also provides RawData or GetRawCertData() on which you can run hash with sha1.ComputeHash(RawData). Both hashes are the same meaning RawData does NOT include signature, Your link simply shows that signature is appended to the end of certificate but it refers to the TRANSMITTED format and not SAVED or made available by Windows. Also, the hash used for thumbprint is not related to this question.

Comment: You mean *this* [`GetCertHash()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/x509certificates/x509certificate.cs,a7b53632c3b56c8e,references)? Thumbprint is not related? I've got 18 years of experience, maybe when you get an answer from somebody with almost 2K of experience on the crypto tag you should doubt yourself instead of him.

Comment: Note that you already doubt Firefox as well. It seems you don't belief anything but your own presumptions. It pays off to doubt your presumptions now and then.

Comment: I assumed thumbprint is a hash of signature alone. But apparently, it is the same as hash of the whole certificate. In any case, thumbprint is outside the scope of this question. My question is where is the signature?

Comment: Assignment: save your raw data, convert to base 64, and paste into [here](https://lapo.it/asn1js/). Or perform `openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in <yourcert.bin>`.

Comment: Windows, IE, Chrome do not display any signature. Firefox is the only one and its signature is the end of certificate data which does not include signature - contradiction

Comment: You did the assignment in 4s?

Comment: For the assignment I would have to run the code again and this has to be in the evening

Comment: OK. For fun you could take the Chrome or IE certificate, save it, and then input it using the web page I just pointed to (it's got a browse button). It uses the same raw data, but you being you I presume you want to check this.

Comment: And, everything checked out?